# Temporary value (local value) with nginx php FPM

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

I have search a lot but not answers found.

i won't to have a lot of pool of PHP FPM, i want it to be like mod_php, and in nginx i wrote :

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "open_basedir = /var/xxx/";
```

It works, but it declare the open_basedir for entiere life of process witch have execute php script (i have done tests). In `phpinfo()`, the `open_basedir` value (this) appears both local value and master value.

i think do a `fastcgi_param` file with a `PHP_VALUE` default value for security, for example (it will certainly never go, but it's principe of security) if a server `{}` have not redefine the `open_basedir` or other values modified (not a lot). I don't like this definitive override, it's dangerous, i sink.

Do you know how to declare to FPM that `fastcgi_param` are always temporary ?? Like Apache `php_admin_value` ... !!!

I have not found the answer, but it's too stupid for not exist !

Comment: Sorry for have not use quote function. Thanks to Francois Deschenes.

Comment: You can try to include your fastcgi.conf above the place in nginx.conf, that redefines fastcgi_param. And both above fastcgi_pass.

Answer (score 2):

Your tests are correct. The set php_value is persistent in the fastcgi process until set to a new value. This can interfere with other virtual host requirements.

The idea behind php fpm is to use different pools for different php value/ini settings, read: different virtual host & php environment settings. So you probably need to define new php-fpm pools for your different virtual hosts.

In case you do not want to define new pools, you will need to overwrite all php_value parameters set for other virtual hosts. That is prone to error!