# Nginx with fastcgi_param caches value for other virtualhosts

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

When I try to auto_prepend a file in one of my virtualhosts I think it is cached by FastCGI and used on another virtualhost as well. The first code block is one of my sites auto prepending a file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site1.com;

    root /var/www/site1;
    index index.php;

    # use fastcgi for all php files
    location ~ \.php$
    {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/file.php";
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The second site does not auto prepend the file but actually does so anyway if site1 is requested in any way before site2. It seems like the "fastcig_param PHP_VALUE" is cached somehow for both sites.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site2.com;

    root /var/www/site2;
    index index.php;

    # use fastcgi for all php files
    location ~ \.php$
    {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13268205/1341058